# Do HTML Headings (<h1> - <h6>) have a default padding or margin in any browser?

Tags: html, css

Someone asked my friend how to remove the space around a heading tag, and he answered with

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

But I've never actually seen padding around a heading. Only margin, in every browser I got. So now I'm wondering, **is there actually any browser, in which there is padding around the headings by default**?

Or is it a standard that all browsers follow, to not put padding around headings? Is the `padding: 0;` unnecessary?

Comment: That is why we have CSS Resets.... Normalizes browsers.

Comment: In addition to browser default it will also handle any global styles you may have defined as well. A css "reset" is for more than just browser defaults.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Headings, by default, have a `padding` of 0. However, an `H1` for example
> has a top and bottom `margin: .67em;`, by default. These top & bottom margins grow all the way to `2.33em` for an `H6`. So for each heading, the top and bottom margins gradually increase by default.

I usually only post from MDN, but unfortunately, they don't have anything on this. Check out this helpful article by [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) which is insightful when discussing the defaults for all HTML elements.

So to answer your question. Yes, the `padding: 0;` is unnecessary. However, the `margin: 0;` will change the default top and bottom margins.