# Hr stopping my elements from moving up (html)

Tags: html, css

I try to put some buttons over a horizontal rule in HTML. I tried with left, up (to put in the up-right corner but hr is stopping my button from moving up).
Here is my code in HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
     .button{
         display:inline-flex;
         height: 25px;
         padding: 0;
         background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         border-radius: 5px;
         overflow: hidden;
         font-family: 'Quicksand' , sans-serif;
         font-size: 15px;
         font-weight: 400;
         cursor:pointer;
         text-align:center;
         position: relative;
         left:600px; up:20px;
     }
 
     .button:hover {
          background: rgb(134, 134, 134);
     }
     
     .button:active {
          background: rgb(158, 157, 157);
     }
     
     .button__text,
     .button__icon{
          display: inline-flex;
          align-items: center;
          padding: 0 3px;
          color: whitesmoke;
          height: 100%;
     }
  </style>
</head>

 <body style="background-color: white;">
 <h1 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Product list</h1>
 <hr>

 <button type="button" class="button">
     <span class="button__icon">
         <ion-icon name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
     </span>
     <span class="button__text">ADD</span>
 </button>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody explain to me how can I resolve this?

Comment: Please include code as text not images.

Comment: HR and H1 are block elements, the styling you added to the button effects the inside of the button. Please add your code as a snippet in order for us to edit your code easily and come with a real answer.

Comment: ok, I am new on this platform and I really didn't know that you can edit my code. I will edit now the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So because you're using an `inline` display property for your button, it would make sense to add the HTML for the `button span` before the `<hr>`. See the additions I made. Also, `h1`'s have a default margin associated with them [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995126/do-html-headings-h1-h6-have-a-default-padding-in-any-browser/69995285#69995285). So you will have to put `margin: 0;` on your h1 to get rid of some of that unnecessary spacing.

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

     .button{
         display:inline-flex;
         height: 25px;
         padding: 0;
         background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         border-radius: 5px;
         overflow: hidden;
         font-family: 'Quicksand' , sans-serif;
         font-size: 15px;
         font-weight: 400;
         cursor:pointer;
         text-align:center;
         position: relative;
         left:600px; 
         top:20px;
     }
 
     .button:hover {
          background: rgb(134, 134, 134);
     }
     
     .button:active {
          background: rgb(158, 157, 157);
     }
     
     .button__text,
     .button__icon{
          display: inline-flex;
          align-items: center;
          padding: 0 3px;
          color: whitesmoke;
          height: 100%;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
</head>

 <body style="background-color: white;">
 <h1 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Product list</h1>
  <button type="button" class="button">
     <span class="button__icon">
         <ion-icon name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
     </span>
     <span class="button__text">ADD</span>
 </button>
 <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

**Click full-page**

Comment: Your code Kameron helped me a lot. But the button is on the hr (In the middle) not over the hr as I needed. I changed the top value to 0, and now its over

Answer (score 0):

Following what you draw in the third image

This code can help you

---

you write that `<hr>` block to go up, but no, you write wrong css (`up`)

- in the first image you use `up` but you need to write `top`)

---

Please note "top" does not take you up, but down

Use this for exercise to learn: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/applied-visual-design/change-an-elements-relative-position

---

```css
.btn {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>random text</div>
<hr>
<button class="btn">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this if you can change `html`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: rgb(134, 134, 134);
}

.button:active {
  background: rgb(158, 157, 157);
}

.button__text,
.button__icon {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 3px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  order: 1;
}

.wrapper .button {
  order: 2;
}

.wrapper hr {
  width: 100%;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Product list</h1>
  <hr>
  <button type="button" class="button">
    <span class="button__icon">
      <ion-icon name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </span>
    <span class="button__text">ADD</span>
  </button>
</div>
```