# Why is there space between my <header> and the border of the page?

Tags: html, css

My page is just a  tag with an  in it. When I set the background-color of the  to black, there is a weird gap between the black background and the page border. Setting the padding and margin on all sides to 0px does not help. Why is this?

```css
#homeHDR {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header id="homeHDR">
  <h1><span id="blueSPN">Papyrus</span>Note</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Very hard to tell without code! Keep in mind that `<body>` has a default padding. Please provide a [MCVE]. In the mean time use the browser developer tools to inspect the header and body elements to see where the margin/padding is coming from.

Comment: If you show us the page's code we might have a better chance of assisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<body>` and `<h1>` tags have a [default margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995126/do-html-headings-h1-h6-have-a-default-padding-or-margin-in-any-browser/69995285#69995285), so resetting them will give you the expected result without any borders:

```css
#homeHDR {
  background-color: black;
}
body, h1 { /* Remove default margin for these guys */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="homeHDR">
  <h1><span id="blueSPN">Papyrus</span>Note</h1>
</header>
```

**Be careful** though. You might only want to reset the margin for the `h1` tag that's inside the `header` to get rid of the ugly border at the top, but **not** other `h1` tags found inside the page *(even though that's discouraged)*. So maybe, you want to have a more specific selector for that `h1`, e.g. `#homeHDR h1 { margin: 0; }`.

---

As **Jon P** correctly pointed out, the `Inspector` and `Elements Panel` in the `DevTools` are the only way to safely detect why these layout issues are happening, e.g. in your case which elements create these spaces, by hovering over the elements.

Margin from `body`:

[image]

Margin from `h1`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There will be a duplicate out there somewhere for this.

`body` has a default margin, generally of 8px. Remove it and your are good

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#homeHDR {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header id="homeHDR">
  <h1><span id="blueSPN">Papyrus</span>Note</h1>
</header>
```

Somewhat more important than this code is getting to know the tools at your disposal. All desktop browsers these days have some variation of "Developer Tools", commonly accessed through f12. Through these you can inspect elements to see that styles have been applied to the elements. By inspecting the `h1` you will see where the vertical spacing is coming from.

Comment: There appears to still be a space above the <header> element.

Comment: @DUSTINNGUYEN That's introduced by the H1 tag. Please check my answer below

Comment: See the explanation in my answer as to how you can  find where this spacing is coming from your self.  It's just as important to know the tools available to you as it is to know code syntax.